# Jenkins with Github and OAuth Stuck in Redirect Loop on Login

Tags: oauth, github, hudson, jenkins, github-api

I have successfully set up Jenkins to pull from my private github repo and build my project, run tests, etc. What I want to do now is automatically build when I push to master.

I have installed the Github OAuth plugin and set it up through Github, but when I log in Jenkins is stuck in a redirect loop.

I registered a new application in Github and set the following values;

> ```
> Name: Jenkins
> URL: http://myServer:8080
> Callback URL: http://myServer:8080
> ```

I cannot find anywhere in any documentation what the correct value for "Callback URL" should be. Is this why it's redirecting?

Comment: I found this question today with the exact same problem for BitBucket but this turned out to be a problem with the plugin and Jenkins 2.150.2, see [JENKINS-55668](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55668?attachmentViewMode=list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally found it:

> Make the callback url look like:
>   http://myserver.com:8080/securityRealm/finishLogin

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by a misconfigured clientSecret (Jenkins side configuration)